# Eclipse luna is not responding

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting these messages in logs:

> MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git.
>
> Hence EGit can't respect system level
>   Git settings which might be configured in `${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig` under the native Git installation directory.
>
> The most important of these settings is `core.autocrlf`. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to `true` in
>   this system level configuration.
>
> The Git installation location can be configured on the: Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
>
> This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
>
> ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-09-15 10:15:02.241
>
> MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
>   user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: `C:\Users\jais`. If this is not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
>   EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
>
> This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
>
> ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 0 2015-09-15 17:06:28.848
>
> MESSAGE The ''com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.ui.contentassist.DojoTypeAttribute'' proposal computer from the ''com.ibm.etools.webtools.dojo.ui'' plug-in did not complete normally. The extension has thrown a runtime exception.
>
> STACK 0

Installed JDK in Environment variable and I tried all possible solutions(like increased the heap memory, in CLI ecllipse -clear,and i unchecked the egit etc), but nothing was working.

Comment: @kenorb did a good job trying to format this, but I'm still confused by what are error messages, and what are your own findings, and above all: what your question is. So, please edit some more, Jai.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/864038/), you have to install the Platform SDK.

This can be achieved in Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers (Eclipse Standard) by installing it from *Eclipse Platform Plug-in Developer Resources*.

Alternatively install it from: *Help→Install New Software→The Eclipse Project Updates*.

The EGit warnings is related to something else.